# the given key was not present in the dictionary error

Tags: c#

the dictionary "_infoCardFactories" is defined as so:

```
 Dictionary<string, IInfoCardFactory> _infoCardFactories;
```

the error "the given key was not present in the dictionary" originates from this line of code:

```
IInfoCard card = _infoCardFactories[category].CreateNewInfoCard(category);
```

here is the interface for the dictionary as well the class it is implemented into.

```
public interface IInfoCardFactory
    {
        IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category);
        IInfoCard CreateInfoCard(string initialDetails);
        string[] CategoriesSupported { get; }
        string GetDescription(string category);
    }

public class creditcard : IInfoCardFactory,IInfoCard
    { 
        public IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category)
        {
           creditcard card = new creditcard();
           return card;
        }

}
```

i cannot show all of the code, due the fact this is an assigment however i would be greatful if someone could help me out.

Comment: pretty straightforward error, you're sending a `string` key with `_infoCardFactories[category]`, but whatever `category` is doesn't exist as a key in the dictionary.

Comment: There is no info card factory with the given `category` in your dictionary. Why that is the case and whether that's the desired state is beyond our capability to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a class based on this interface and then define your dictionary to use that implementation. There needs to be an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `IInfoCard card = _infoCardFactories[category].CreateNewInfoCard(category);`

Use this:

```
IInfoCard card;
IInfoCardFactory factory;
if (_infoCardFactories.TryGetValue(category, out factory))
     card = factory.CreateNewInfoCard(category);
else
{
    // when category is not in your dictionary
}
```